# How to return text based on 2 criterion

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tGz0pMeds01kuyK1ZNuvQd9UiiS7iPcRbUL_23mdhfg/edit#gid=0

I have this formula in column K: `=IF(COUNTIF($H:$H, $A15)=0, "No match in h", "")`

This scans column H and compares each value in H with each cell in column A (A15 in above example) and checks if there is a matching value or not.

It returns no match if there is no match, and nothing in case of match.

I want to add another criteria, which is, if the amounts in column C & G match.

In better words, if H:H compared to A5 yields a match in let's say cell H200. Then in this case, we need to check if G200 has same amount of $$ as C5.

Because we need to match order IDs as well as amounts.

I'm not sure this is possible with built-in formulas, so I was looking for scripts online. I read google's spreadsheet app script documentation and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but try this:

```
=IF($H:$H<>$A$15, "No match in H",if(G:G<>$C$5,"No match in G",""))
```

Comment: Hi Ed,
Thanks for your input. 
However, that just checks A15 in H:H and C15 in G:G separately. 

My condition is linked, as in, if A15 is found in H:H, let's say H25. In this case, C15 should also match G25.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

```
=IFERROR(
  IF(INDEX(G:G,MATCH(A5,H:H,0))=C5,"Has the same amount","Hasn't the same amount"), 
  "No match in h"
)
```

## Explanation

Use MATCH to find the index of column H value that matches the lookup value from column A
then
Use INDEX to get the value from column G.
then
Compare the returned value with value in column C

If there is a match, return there is match statement
If there is not a match, return there isn't match statement
If there is no match on column H, return there is no match on column H statement